# How to append text to the richTextBox from another class in C# Winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a Winform named`Form1` with a RichTextBox named`richTextBox1`.  Also I have created a method called `update` which does the work of displaying message in the richTextBox1.  When I tried to invoke it from `Class1` it is not working.  Whereas I am to see the message in the MessageBox whereas not in the `richTextBox1`.  Here is the piece of code.

Code: Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void update(string message)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("mess: " + message);
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 sample = new Class1();            
        } 
    }
```

Class1.cs

```
public class Class1
    {        
        public Class1()
        {
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.update("Sampe");
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

**Class1.cs**

```
 class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            Form1._Form1.update("Sampe");
        } 
    }
```

**Form1.cs**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _Form1 = this;
        }
        public static  Form1 _Form1;
        public void update(string message)
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("mess: " + message);
            MessageBox.Show(message);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 sample = new Class1();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great, this is working.  Thank you.  Can you please explain this.

Comment: before form 1 showed i make an static instance of form1 so i can access its function with out make it new.you have a mistake when you init class1 in class1 you make an instance of form1 so it is like it that you create new form.